# how to access data in such table?

Tags: lua

I'm writing a program with lua. I have data that organized in the following way:

```
t= {
    i1 = {
        p1 = { value = "i1p1" },
        p2 = { value = "i1p2" }, 
        -- etc
        pm = { value = "i1pm" }
    },
    i2 = {
        p1 = { value = "i2p1" },
        p2 = { value = "i2p2" },
        -- etc
        pm = { value = "i2pm" }
    },
    im = {
        p1 = { value = "imp1" },
        p2 = { value = "imp2" },
         -- etc
        pm = { value = "impm" }
    }
} --(inner tables)
```

In another way each group of data is indexed by two variables i&p,I am sure that the data is kept correctly but I want a way to print the data from their tables because I won't know the values of i and p to iterate over them or even the numbers n & m any body know how to do this with lua?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking for. Can you reorganize your question to be more clear about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I see a lot of function calls with the shortcut notation `f{} == f({})` ... You might try and get your example code correct, and correctly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the depth of your nested (inner) tables, you can iterate explicitly to that depth:

```
for k1,v1 in pairs(t) do
    for k2,v2 in pairs(v1) do
        for k3, v3 in pairs(v2) do
            print(k3, ":", v3)
        end
    end
end
```

Alternatively, you can recursively iterate into your nested structure:

```
function print_tbl(tbl)
    if type(tbl) == "table" then
        for _,v in pairs(tbl) do
            print_tbl(v)
        end
    else
        print(tbl)
    end
end

print_tbl(t)
```

This is just an example. If your tables contain functions, contains userdata, or your nesting has cycles, you'll need a different approach. Take a look at [table serialization](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization) on the Lua user wiki. Serialization requires sensible handling of tables with nesting, functions, cycles, etc. You may be able to use lessons learned on your data.